# Is it poor style to hide instance variables in filters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see this all the time in rails code:

```
before filter :get_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

def edit
  # code .......
end

def update
  # code .......
end

def destroy
  # code .......
end

private
  def get_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I understand it keeps from repeating the same line of code three times, but isn't there a much easier to read and better way to accomplish the same thing by just refactoring the code into a private method without hiding the instance variable and the before filter?

```
private
  def get_post(post_id)
    Post.find(post_id)
  end
```

Then you can keep the instance variable in the action

```
def edit
  @post = get_post(params[:id])
end
```

It doesn't make sense conceptually to hide instance variables in private methods. Why is this so prevalent in rails?

Comment: Check this gem: https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably see a lot of differing opinions on this particular practice. *Personally*, I agree with you; I feel that the strict adherence to DRY only serves to introduce a bit of confusion by hiding away the instance variable in a method down at the bottom of the file. I'm not even sure a `get_post` method really buys you very much myself. That said, I tend to prefer explicicity (if that's a word) over terseness in many cases, and for a team that uses this trick consistently in every controller, there may not be as much (if any) confusion.

If the filter encapsulates a little more complexity, it may be worth it. For example, the popular authorization library [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) by Ryan Bates introduces a controller class macro called `load_and_authorize_resource` that installes `before_filter`s such that RESTful resources are automatically loaded and authorized for access against the current user. This could potentially be more than a line or two per method, and would not repeated verbatim each time.

There's a popular middle-ground that some Rails devs use, which is to specify the `before_filter` as a block, so you don't have to repeat yourself, but the instance variable is up at the top of the file:

```
before_filter(only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]) do
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

As mentioned in the comments, there are some gems, like [decent_exposure](https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure), which help formalize this pattern and make it significantly less "hidden" or confusing (since it's declared explicitly and the API is known).

Comment: I definitely like your suggestion the best about putting the instance variable in a block at the top with the before filter. It seems to read better and the instance variable is not hidden away.

Answer (score 2):

As other have stated, this is a matter of opinion. I started off using before filters to hide common instance variables between controllers. I still do this on occasion, but I have found it to be a code smell that the controller is bloated. If you have so many instance variables that you need to hide them in filters you are doing too much. My opinion is that the controller action should be very small, and if all the actions have one line in common that handles the instance variable its not an issue.

My remedy for getting my controller actions to a level that made me comfortable with having a common instance variable was to use service object/presenters to consolidate the information that was once in several instance variables into a single instance variable per controller action. I've found this been a huge improvement in the readability and maintainability of my controllers and views.

Answer (score 1):

I think your suggestion is an improvement over the typical Rails convention.  I'd take it a step farther, though and drop the instance variable entirely.  It's misleading to use an instance variable because it's typically not representing shared state across multiple controller actions, and often not even shared between any methods (except the before filter that assigns it).

The Rails convention of populating an instance variable for use in a view is a bad idea whose use should disappear.  In a clean MVC implementation, nothing from the controller would be available in the view.  I think this is a much cleaner implementation which properly separates the layers:

```
def edit
  post = get_post(params[:post_id])
  render 'edit', locals: { post: post }
end
```

No leaking state, no reliance on an instance variable in the view, explicit intent, and a view that is more easily reusable and can be rendered from within other views without injecting a hacky inline instance variable assignment.

Rails has a number of conventions that make for quick bootstrapping, but they don't make for good code.

Comment: Agreed - I think yours is the best answer. Sometimes you have to work on a large application before you realize why good principles are good. It seems like the rails community has yet to fully buy in to OO principles like encapsulation / isolating state.

Answer (score 0):

It's a convention over configuration thing.

Neither approach is wrong, but people who like Ruby often prefer minimalist coding patterns, and value using the quickest approach to solve a problem so they can get on to solving more complex and interesting problems

If one has seen this approach used often enough, it becomes second nature to have all of the member functions (obviously not the collection functions) preload the member variable for you before you define your code.  It gets to the point where specifying the member variables in the function does not create a significant clarity advantage (if any).

Answer (score 0):

There is also another approach using `helper_method`. It's looks almost as you want it.

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/57-substituting-before_filter-load_object