# What should I do with a repeatedly used chunk of code that includes ruby & CSS?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry, helper

I've neglected the DRY principle of ruby on rails for a long time. I use this same chunk of code over and over in different view files:

```
<div class="challenge-accomplished-date-banner">
  <% if @correct_user %>
    <%= challenge.notes.count.to_s.rjust(2, "0") %>
  <% else %>
    <%= challenge.notes.publish.count.to_s.rjust(2, "0") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% if challenge.categorization == "adventure" %>
  <%= link_to categorization_path(categorization: :adventure) do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture", id="challenge-flag"></span>
  <% end %>
<% elsif challenge.categorization == "health" %>
  <%= link_to categorization_path(categorization: :health) do %>   
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart", id="challenge-flag"></span>
  <% end %>            
<% elsif challenge.categorization == "work" %>
  <%= link_to categorization_path(categorization: :work) do %>    
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase", id="challenge-flag"></span>
  <% end %>
<% elsif challenge.categorization == "gift" %>
  <%= link_to categorization_path(categorization: :gift) do %>    
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous", id="challenge-flag"></span>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to categorization_path(categorization: :wacky) do %>    
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass", id="challenge-flag"></span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<% if challenge.duels.present? && challenge.duels.last.duelers.order(id: :asc).last.accept =! false %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower", id="challenge-flag"></span>
<% elsif challenge.conceal == true %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close", id="challenge-flag"></span>
<% else %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open", id="challenge-flag"></span>      
<% end %>
```

Not sure what to do with it? Do I put it in...

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def banner
    # See Above Code Chunk
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work with CSS? Is there a way to allow CSS in the helper? Or do I put this chunk of code somewhere else like in the model, but then I run into the same CSS problem? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the CSS? I can't see any here.

Comment: `<div class="challenge-accomplished-date-banner">` and I think the `<span>` classes would also constitute as CSS @Amadan

Comment: No, `.challenge-accomplished-date-banner { .... }` (in either a `.css` file or in the body of a `<style>` tag) consititutes CSS. Class attribute on an HTML element is still just a text attribute of HTML. What problem do you have with  the class attribute in a helper? What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: If it's a method from a CSS file doesn't that make it CSS? And if copy and paste that code into an application_helper.rb you'll see the formatting is all thrown off because I guess helper's don't recognize CSS @Amadan

Comment: a) `challenge-accomplished-date-banner` is a HTML class name, not a method. b) No, it does not make it CSS. HTML classes can be manipulated by JavaScript, for example, and need not be used for CSS at all. c) `application_helper.rb` is a Ruby file, it needs Ruby, not HTML (and incidentally and irrelevantly not CSS either). You can render HTML from a helper file by putting it into a string, or rendering it from a partial view.

Comment: What do you think would be better than a partial view or a string? If a string, then how can I do that? And I see what you're saying now thank you. The HTML class name is there for purposes of CSS @Amadan

Comment: You have ERb in it, so definitely partial.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying this for me @Amadan. I'll give you thumbs up elsewhere as a thank you :)

Comment: Thanks, but you really shouldn't: it would be detected as vote manipulation, and is kind of against the rules :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `CATEGORIES` constant

```
CATEGORIES = {
  adventure: 'glyphicon-picture',
  health:    'glyphicon-heart',
  work:      'glyphicon-briefcase',
  gift:      'glyphicon-tree-deciduous'
}

CATEGORIES.default = 'glyphicon-glass'
```

Create partials

**_flag.html.erb**

```
<span class="glyphicon <%= class_name %>", id="challenge-flag"></span>
```

**_link.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to categorization_path(categorization: category) do %>    
  <%= render 'flag', class_name: class_name %>
<% end %>
```

And use them

```
<% category = challenge.categorization %>
<% class_name = CATEGORIES[category.to_sym] %>

<%= render 'link', class_name: class_name, category: category %>
```

Comment: Why would I do this when I could just put the code chunk in a partial _banner.html.erb? Will your alternative make the site faster or is it a best practice or something? I'm still a beginner so I'm curious why one way works better than another. Thanks!

Comment: 1. DRY code 2. removed the conditions `if - elsif - else- end` 3. less line of code

Comment: 4. easy to understand (with basic knowledge of ruby)

Comment: Okay well said :) I'm running to an `uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::CATEGORIES` error

Comment: Maybe that's creating a conflict with `CATEGORY = ['goal', 'habit']`? I have in challenge table as columns: `category` and `categorization`

Comment: You can change the constant name anytime. Make sure the constant is accessible where you are using it or define it in a Challenge class and use it as class constant e.g Challenge::CATEGORIES

Comment: Okay I added `Challenge::CATEGORIES` in place of `CATEGORIES`, which removed error :) What do I do with the rest of the code chunk? Should I just put that in _flag too and then pass `challenge` to the partial?

Comment: You can use the code where you were using the previous one

Comment: third snippet in my answer removes the middle block of if -else from your code

Comment: Even though this is DRY, I'd say a model constant should not contain view logic like an icon's class [See this related question on the MVC pattern and separation of concerns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658/rails-model-view-controller-and-helper-what-goes-where).

Answer (score 1):

You can define the following method on a helper:

```
def challenge_link(category)
  icon = case category
  when 'adventure' then 'picture'
  when 'health' then 'heart'
  when 'work' then 'briefcase'
  when 'gift' then 'tree-deciduous'
  else
    'glass'
  end

  link_to(categorization_path(categorization: category.to_sym)) do
    content_tag(:span, "", class: "glyphicon glyphicon-#{ icon }", id: "challenge-flag")
  end
end
```

And then call it from the view like this:

```
<%= challenge_link('adventure') %>
```

Regarding the css, just make sure the `challenge-accomplished-date-banner` class is general enough so that you can reuse it in several areas of your app.

If you want to go further, you can consider defining `@challenge_notes` and `@challenge_flag` on a before_action on your controller and using the following code in your view:

```
<div class="challenge-accomplished-date-banner">
  <%= @challenge_notes %>
</div>

<%= challenge_link('adventure') %>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-<%= @challenge_icon %>", id="challenge-flag"></span>
```

Comment: I'd advise to choose a helper (as this answer suggests) over rendering a template, as templates are relatively slow to render and in this case there is no real benefit to it, `link_to` and `content_tag` provide exactly what you need.